# Jpamodelgen not generating metamodel classes on update to Quarkus 3.2.3

Tags: quarkus, jpamodelgen

I just updated my project to Quarkus 3.2.2.Final but hibernate-jpamodelgen dependency is not working. Already tried multiple versions.

It is not generating metamodel classes for my project.

It works on Quarkus versions 2.x.x

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.138.0</version>
    <description>my project</description>
    <name>my project</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <dependency.locations.enabled>false</dependency.locations.enabled>
        <apache-poi.version>5.2.1</apache-poi.version>
        <powermock.version>1.7.4</powermock.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.2.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
        <azure-storage-blob.version>12.14.4</azure-storage-blob.version>
        <azure-identity.version>1.4.6</azure-identity.version>
        <azure-resourcemanager.version>2.6.0</azure-resourcemanager.version>
        <azure-sdk-bom.version>1.1.1</azure-sdk-bom.version>
        <microsoft-graph.version>5.18.0</microsoft-graph.version>
        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.7</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <opencsv.version>5.6</opencsv.version>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-report/jacoco.xml
        </sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/java</sonar.tests>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
            **/infrastructure/database/criteria/*,
            **/api/filters/**/*,
            **/api/dto/**/*,
            **/domain/exception/**/*
        </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Used to build the response objects returned by the API - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-reactive -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to to document the REST API with OpenAPI - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-smallrye-openapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for build time CDI dependency injection - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-arc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for scheduling periodic tasks - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-scheduler -->
        <!-- Cron examples: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-scheduler</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to create a data access layer using JPA - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to annotate the REST services - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to define the persistence model with Hibernate ORM and JPA - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to validate object properties - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>32.0.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for serialization support for RESTEasy Reactive - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to establish the connection to PSQL database - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-jdbc-postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-liquibase</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for automatic code generation - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-test-security</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-test-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.28.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used to be able to mock static functions - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-inline -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${apache-poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-storage-blob -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-storage-blob.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-identity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>${microsoft-graph.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                            <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                            <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                            <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
                            <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>${maven.compiler.parameters}</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                        <version>2.8</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>lt.velykis.maven.skins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>reflow-velocity-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    <wtpContextName>personalized-news</wtpContextName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/jacoco-report</outputDirectory>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>${sonar.coverage.exclusions}</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-functional-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/functional-test/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_HOST}:${env.DB_PORT}/${env.DB_LM_NAME}</url>
                    <username>${env.DB_USER}</username>
                    <password>${env.DB_PASS}</password>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <show>private</show>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner
                                        </native.image.path>
                                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <reporting>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <reportSets>
                            <reportSet>
                                <reports>
                                    <report>report</report>
                                </reports>
                            </reportSet>
                        </reportSets>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </reporting>
            <properties>
                <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

the dependency for jpamodelgen

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do you have any clue how to address this?

Comment: Please edit the question with the full `pom.xml`.

Comment: Added the full pom.xml

Comment: That's on Quarkus 2.14 not on Quarkus 3.x

Comment: Sorry that was the version I had before the update.
I updated the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't generating JPA metamodel; it wasn't being compiled.

However, Quarkus provides `hibernate-jpamodelgen` as managed dependency, coordinates of this artifacts (especially the groupId) had changed. You mentioned the right dependency at the end of the question but the outdated one is on the `pom.xml`

If you try to compile that

```
mvn clean package -DskiptTests
```

you will get an error:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar is missing. @ line 269, column 21
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:my-project:1.138.0 (/work/source/quarkus-jpa-metamodel/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:jar is missing. @ line 269, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
```

Replace

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to this:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

#### Bonus answer for a question that hasn't been asked

Quarkus 3 has a lot of major upgrades. One of theese that Quarkus 3 using Hibernate ORM 6.2 as a 3rd party library.

I discovered that project depends on `Hibernate Types` but it hasn't been updated from Hibernate 5.x to 6.2.
Before you get other incompatibility issues I recommend to migrate from :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Migration guide is available on

- GitHub - [How to migrate to Hypersistence Utils 3](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/issues/536)
- Vlad Mihalcea's blog - [From Hibernate Types to Hypersistence Utils](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-types-hypersistence-utils/)